# Magento Layered Navigation on Product Details

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add layered navigation in product details page.

I managed to show layered navigation in product details by adding following layout in *catalog_product_view* page.

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="product.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
    <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>3</category_id></action>
</block>
```

The problem is that links in layered navigation takes the current page URL rather than category page URL - which results to be remains in same page rather than listing the products for the category.